Mockito Exception for mocking interface HttpServletRequest
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
Mockito cannot mock this class: interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.
Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.
Java               : 1.8
JVM vendor name    :
JVM vendor version : 25.232-b09
JVM name           : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 1.8.0_232-b09
JVM info           : mixed mode
OS name            : Windows 10
OS version         : 10.0
Here, I'm trying to a Junit set up and run a test file in a gradle based projectwhich is not using any framework and these are my project configurations,
Gradle : 5.5
Java : 1.8
Junit4 : 4.12
Mockito-core : 2.22.0
for junit and mockito added the below dependency,
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12' testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.22.0'
can you help me understand why am I getting this exception?

That looks strange - please check the  (test-)runtime versions of your HttpServlet implentation.

Current versions of that use the 'sealed' keyword, but that didn't exist in java 8.

What version of servlet-api do you use?

Tried with both java.servlet-api 3.0.1 and 4.0.1 but same error
